# How to indicate type constraints in class diagram for generic type?

Tags: java, generics, interface, uml, class-diagram

I've the following interface:

```
interface EvolutionaryAlgorithm <EVOLUTIONARILY_OPTIMIZABLE_TYPE extends EvolutionarilyOptimizable<CHROMOSOME_TYPE, COST_TYPE>,
                                 CHROMOSOME_TYPE extends ChromosomeElement,
                                 COST_TYPE> {
    //...
}
```

I am creating a clas diagram for this interface. The generic type parameters are added to this interface

[image]

What is the proper way to indicate type constraints, like

```
EVOLUTIONARILY_OPTIMIZABLE_TYPE extends EvolutionarilyOptimizable<CHROMOSOME_TYPE, COST_TYPE>
```

on this diagram?
Is it possible to solve this problem with StarUml?

Answer (score 0):

You would show it like this:

[image]

where `Class` is the type constraint.

I have no idea whether StarUML can show this. Worst case: use an appropriately formatted string.